# Why my .bib file is not recognized by Overleaf compiler in ApJ template?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, aastex, multiple-citations

I am writing a paper on *overleaf* supposedly in `ApJ` (Astrophysical Journal) format. I have my `.bib` file independently made utilizing **JabRef** on *ADS website* and uploaded to the project in *Overleaf*. But it seems that in-text citations do not appear in the final version after compiling. In particular, here is my short version of the code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,trackchanges]{aastex61}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{epsf}

\begin{document}
.
.
.
\section{Methodology and Analyses}  \label{Section 2}
....This includes absorbers selected for the presence of \ion{C}{4}
$\lambda \lambda1548.1,1550.7$, \ion{Mg}{2} $\lambda\lambda2796.3,2803.5$
resonance-line doublets and Lyman limit absorption, which do not also 
qualify as DLA systems. For a complete review on the subject refer to 
\citet{2005ARA&A..43..861W}. 

\bibliographystyle{ApJ}
\bibliography{my_References}
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

Here is the Error Message:

> (no line number): This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
>   Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009 The
>   top-level auxiliary file: sim_DLA_Paper.aux I couldn't open style file
>   ApJ.bst
>   ---line 126 of file sim_DLA_Paper.aux  : \bibstyle{ApJ  :              } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style
>   file---while reading file sim_DLA_Paper.aux You've used 46 entries,
>               0 wiz_defined-function locations,
>               178 strings with 2287 characters, and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
>   = -- 0
>
> > -- 0 < -- 0
> >     + -- 0
> >     - -- 0
> >     * -- 0 := -- 0 add.period$ -- 0 call.type$ -- 0 change.case$ -- 0 chr.to.int$ -- 0 cite$ -- 0 duplicate$ -- 0 empty$ -- 0 format.name$
> >     -- 0 if$ -- 0 int.to.chr$ -- 0 int.to.str$ -- 0 missing$ -- 0 newline$ -- 0 num.names$ -- 0 pop$ -- 0 preamble$ -- 0 purify$ -- 0 quote$ -- 0 skip$ -- 0 stack$ -- 0 substring$ -- 0 swap$ -- 0 text.length$ -- 0
> >     text.prefix$ -- 0 top$ -- 0 type$ -- 0 warning$ -- 0 while$ -- 0
> >     width$ -- 0 write$ -- 0 (There were 2 error messages)
> >     ./sim_DLA_Paper.tex:75: Package natbib Warning: Citation
> >     `2005ARA&A..43..861W' on page 2 undefined on i nput line 75.
> >     ./sim_DLA_Paper.tex:80: Package natbib Warning: Citation`
> >     2003MNRAS.342..962S' on page 2 undefined on i nput line 80.
>
> Package natbib Warning: Citation `2003JApA...24...51G' on page 2
>   undefined on i nput line 80.
>
> Package natbib Warning: Citation `2005MNRAS.356..778S' on page 2
>   undefined on i nput line 80.
>
> Package natbib Warning: Citation `1974A&A....32..391P' on page 2
>   undefined on i nput line 80. ./sim_DLA_Paper.tex:81: Package natbib
>   Warning: Citation`2005CSci...88.1088B' on page 2 undefined on i nput
>   line 81. ./sim_DLA_Paper.tex:83: Package natbib Warning: Citation
>   `2011MNRAS.416.1215R' on page 2 undefined on i nput line 83.
>
> Package natbib Warning: Citation `2016A&A...596A..97D' on page 2
>   undefined on i nput line 83.
>
> Package natbib Warning: Citation `2016MNRAS.460.2675R' on page 2
>   undefined on i nput line 83. ./sim_DLA_Paper.tex:85: Package natbib
>   Warning: Citation`2014MNRAS.445..581H' on page 3 undefined on i nput
>   line 85.

Here is the the first two entries of `.bib` file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{2005ARA&A..43..861W,
  author  = {{Wolfe}, A.~M. and {Gawiser}, E. and {Prochaska}, J.~X.},
  title   = {{Damped Ly {$\alpha$} Systems}},
  journal = {\araa},
  year    = {2005},
  volume  = {43},
  pages   = {861-918},
  month   = sep,
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl  = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005ARA%26A..43..861W},
  doi     = {10.1146/annurev.astro.42.053102.133950},
  eprint  = {astro-ph/0509481},
  file    = {:2005ARA&A..43..861W - Damped Ly $_alpha$ Systems.pdf:PDF},
}

@Article{2005MNRAS.364.1467Z,
  author   = {{Zwaan}, M.~A. and {van der Hulst}, J.~M. and {Briggs}, F.~H. and {Verheijen}, M.~A.~W. and {Ryan-Weber}, E.~V.},
  title    = {{Reconciling the local galaxy population with damped Lyman {$\alpha$} cross-sections and metal abundances}},
  journal  = {\mnras},
  year     = {2005},
  volume   = {364},
  pages    = {1467-1487},
  month    = dec,
  adsnote  = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl   = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005MNRAS.364.1467Z},
  doi      = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2005.09698.x},
  eprint   = {astro-ph/0510127},
  file     = {:2005MNRAS.364.1467Z - Reconciling the local galaxy population with damped Lyman $_alpha$ cross-sections and metal abundances.pdf:PDF},
  keywords = {surveys, galaxies: ISM, quasars: absorption lines, galaxies: statistics, radio lines: galaxies},
}
```

I can see that `.bib` file is contained citations in the form of `MNRAS`. I think they should instead be all `ApJ`. But, it is really a long file and I don't know if I need to manipulate all sources one by one. When I change the option `ApJ` to `mnras` in the following command `\bibliographystyle{}`, in-text citations appear but why is that? Why style `ApJ` is not recognized?

Comment: Please show two bib entrys in your question and add to the MWE how you call them ...

Comment: .bib entries are not styled _at all_ that is the function of the `\bibliographystyle{ApJ}` command, to instruct bibtex how to style the references. Have you run bibtex?  also, why are you loading `epsf`

Comment: I just added two entries of the bib file called my_references.bib. I just left that package since it was already in the ApJ template. To be honest, I am not sure why I left that intact.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the comment. How can I run bibtex in overleaf? when I run it in latex independently on my computer (in mnras) format, there is no issue. But I need to do it in ApJ on overleaf.

Comment: Upload the `Apj.bst` file to your project on OverLeaf. You don't have to do anything to run BibTeX - it is automatic. But it can't find the style file it needs. You must have it locally, so just add it to your project.

Comment: hi, i work for AAS journals. this Overleaf template is designed to use \bibliographystyle{aasjournal}, which is our Journal's current bibtex style. If you have problems running with that please let us know. If you have some reason to prefer the outdated \bibliographystyle{apj} then upload this file: http://ads.harvard.edu/pubs/bibtex/astronat/apj/apj.bst to your Overleaf project -- as is (i.e., without renaming it anything else including no capitalization of the filename, which could be half your problem) and then use  \bibliographystyle{apj} (again no capitals and no need for capitals).

Comment: @Gus 7, my only reason was to submit the letter to ApJ. I have no other reason to use the outdated one. And, I tried the new version. Thanks, it has no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> \bibstyle{ApJ : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

tells you that the bibliography style is unknown to overleaf.  You need to add a file `apj.bst` to your project, that means add it into the same directory you have your TeX file.

You can for example find a link to `apj.bst` on the [website of aastex](https://aastex2.aas.org/aastex/aasguide.html) in section `2.13.2 Specifying Bibliographic and Citation Information`.

Comment: Trying to make a .bst file

Comment: Overleaf has an embedded aasjournal.bst

Comment: I don't know how to make apj.bst when it's missing in overleaf. I cannot open the content to replace it with the contents you provided in that section of aastex.

Comment: I can only copy into .txt file and nothing else.

Comment: I just renamed whatever they had in as aasjournal.bst into ApJ.bst. Interestingly, the letters being small or capital is very important in the name of the file. For example apj.bst just didn't work.

Comment: Yes, @Allan these are case specific compiler platforms. This  Overleaf template is designed to use aasjournals.bst and \bibliographystyle{aasjournal}. See my other comment about the desire to use the older apj.bst file above. Let us know if you need other help.